# New to SQL. Would like to convert an IF(COUNTIFS()) Excel formula to SQL code and have SQL calculate it instead of Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel-formula, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM).

I have a SQL query that pulls Dates, Products, Customers and Units:

```
select 

[Transaction Date] as Date, 
[SKU] as Product, 
[Customer Name] as Customer, 
sum(Qty) as Units 

from dataset

where [Transaction Date] < '2019-03-01' and [Transaction Date] >= '2016-01-01'

group by [Transaction Date], [SKU], [Customer Name]

order by [Transaction Date]
```

This pulls hundreds of thousands of records and I wanted to determine if a certain transaction was a new order or reorder based on the following logic:

**Reorder: That specific Customer has ordered that specific product in the last 6 months**

**New Order: That specific Customer hasn’t ordered that specific product in the last 6 months**

For that I have this formula in Excel that seems to be working:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,">="&DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)-6,DAY(A2)),C$1:C1,C2,B$1:B1,B2),"Reorder","New Order")
```

The formula works when I paste it individually or in a smaller dataset, but when I try to copy paste it to all 500K+ rows, Excel gives up because it loops for each calculation.

This could probably be done in SQL, but I don’t have the knowledge on how to convert this excel formula to SQL, I just started studying it.

Comment: And how are we supposed to know what your Excel cells contains except A2 containing a date, please add an explanation. Also add some sample data and expected output. What database are you using, please add the correct tag to your question. Lastly, is that sql query really working, a SUM() function usually requires a GROUP BY?

Comment: Hi Joakim. I'm sorry, this is my first time posting here. I didn't know the [where / group by/ order by] parts of my query were relevant to the question. Apart from that I don't really understand your other guidelines. Column A contains transaction dates with A1 being the header. Expected output would be for the query to check if that customer purchased that specific product in the last 6 months. If yes, then it's a reorder, if not it's a new order.

Comment: It's good to minimize but not to much since it can make it unclear if you have an error in your code, about the excel code well maybe I read to much into that and it is not so relevant for the question

Comment: The server is Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing pretty well with the start of your query there.  There are three additional functions you're looking to add to your query.

The first thing you'll need is the easiest.  `GETDATE()` simply returns the current date.  You'll need that when you're comparing the current date to the transaction date.

The second function is `DATEDIFF`, which will give you a unit of time between two dates (months, days, years, quarters, etc).  Using `DATEDIFF`, you can say "is this date within the last 6 months".  The format for this is pretty easy.  It's `DATEDIFF(interval, date1, date2)`.

The thrid function you're looking for is `CASE`, which allows you to tell SQL to give you one answer if one condition is met, but a different answer if a different condition is met.  For your example, you can say "if the difference in days is < 60, return 'Reorder', if not give me 'New Order'".

Putting it all together:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, [Transaction Date], GETDATE()) <= 6
            THEN 'Reorder'
        ELSE 'New Order'
        END as ORDER_TYPE
    ,[Transaction Date] AS DATE
    ,[SKU] AS PRODUCT
    ,[Customer Name] AS CUSTOMER
    ,Qty AS UNITS
FROM DATASET
```

- For additonal examples on CASE, take a look at this site:  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_case.asp
- For additional examples on DATEDIFF, take a look here:  See the
  following webpage for examples and a chance to try it out: 
  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp

Comment: Hi Moose, Thank you for your detailed answer! This does not have the desired output, it shows transactions up until a certain date to be all new orders and then every transaction is a reorder. What I would like is for the script to check if that specific customer purchased that specific product in the last 6 months and if the customer did, then it would be a reorder, if it did not, then it would be a new order.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Datediff(day, [transaction date], Getdate()) <= 180 THEN 'reorder'
         ELSE 'Neworder'
       END,
       [transaction date] AS Date,
       [sku]              AS Product,
       [customer name]    AS Customer,
       qty                AS Units
FROM   datase
```

Comment: Besides code, I think your answer should provide an explanation of what it does.

Comment: Especially if the first three words in the title of the question are "New to SQL".

Comment: Hi Rocky, Thank you for your answer! This does not have the desired output, it shows transactions up until a certain date to be all new orders and then every transaction is a reorder. What I would like is for the script to check if that specific customer purchased that specific product in the last 6 months and if the customer did, then it would be a reorder, if it did not, then it would be a new order.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to peak at the previous date and make a comparison.  This suggests `lag()`:

```
select (case when lag([Transaction Date]) over (partition by SKU, [Customer Name] order by [Transaction Date]) >
                  dateadd(month, -6, [Transaction Date])
             then 'Reorder'
             else 'New Order'
        end) as Order_Type
       [Transaction Date] as Date, 
       [SKU] as Product, 
       [Customer Name] as Customer, 
       sum(Qty) as Units 
from dataset d
group by [Transaction Date], [SKU], [Customer Name];
```

EDIT:

In SQL Server 2008, you can emulate the `LAG()` using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select (case when dprev.[Transaction Date] >
                  dateadd(month, -6, d.[Transaction Date])
             then 'Reorder'
             else 'New Order'
        end) as Order_Type
       d.[Transaction Date] as Date, 
       d.[SKU] as Product, 
       d.[Customer Name] as Customer, 
       sum(d.Qty) as Units 
from dataset d outer apply
     (select top (1) dprev.*
      from dataset dprev
      where dprev.SKU = d.SKU and
            dprev.[Customer Name] = d.[Customer Name] and
            dprev.[Transaction Date] < d.[Transaction Date]
      order by dprev.[Transaction Date] desc
     ) dprev
group by d.[Transaction Date], d.[SKU], d.[Customer Name];
```

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thank you for your input! As I mentioned I'm still new to SQL and didn't know that I had to post the SQL server into my question as well. I tried running the lag function and it said 'lag' is not a recognized built-in function name. After that I checked and saw that lag only works 2012 and onwards, and my server is 2008.